# Any trick on how to increase frames per second cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Ok so I just recently learned a trick about the rotation and how that increase fps, but I thought that there should be more tricks like this and was wondering if you guys can share some. Im talking more about the hidden ones that I might not find out. I did see something about the background and how you can raise fps a tad more by splitting it into pieces.
    http://www.uchidacoonga.com/2011/03/increase-frame-rate-to-60-fps-in-cocos2d/

Comment: I have no idea what that "trick about rotation" you're referring to entails. I hardly get how splitting the background can raise your fps "a tad more". You're very vague with your examples, that's not encouraging for others to follow this up with excellent detailed examples. It's also not a question, and it can't be answered definitively. You might want to post this on the cocos2d forum instead, you'll find more open minds for subjective discussions and exchange of experiences in a forum.

Comment: Ok here the link for the rotation.

Comment: You're right about the autorotation on older devices. But hardly anyone cares about the old devices anymore, most people want to hear about the new stuff. And especially things that are not available on the cocos2d wiki itself.

Comment: Yeah,but I was just wondering if there anything in cocos2d itself that I can change that will make my app run better.

Comment: Do you have an actual performance problem? Then measure it, and find a way to make what is currently slow faster. All other and specifically the sort of general performance enhancing tips, besides sprite batching, are hardly worth considering. Lastly, there's no point in increasing performance as long as your game is running at 60 fps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use spritesheets, add children to them to prevent multiple texture bindings per frame.
2. Use smaller textures
3. Have only one update method, don't let events drive transforms on sprites. For example. instead of letting a ccTouchesBegan change the sprites position, remember the touch state and work with it in the main update method. This is useful for accelerometerDidAccelerate, especially
4. If your update cycle is heavy due to some heavy algorithms such as face recognition and such, use deltaTime, schedule less frequent updates.
5. If you are using GCC, you can enable THUMB instructions.
6. use POD (int, float structs), c functions and c arrays inside your update loop, rather than NSObjects, NSArrays, Methods

Comment: Now this is what I am talking about! Now what exactly is THUMB?

Comment: you can find thumb instructions manual here: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:best_practices

Comment: How does #3 help with performance? #5 is practically obsolete, all devices since iPhone 3GS are using THUMB unless you turned that setting off (and GCC is on its way out too). #6 is dangerous; though you can squeeze out a few cycles the C functions/arrays should only be used when you have an actual performance issue there, and nothing else to optimize. Not using NS* classes will definitely hurt the coder's performance.

Comment: That's what I mean. While there are some good suggestions here, others are dangerous or bad advice if applied without considering the actual application scenario and without confirming them by measurements. It's the reason why I don't like those "performance enhancing tips". Accepting this as an answer gives the suggestions even more credibility. And more developers might apply them without thinking twice.

Comment: #2 "Use smaller textures" is misleading and could cause some devs to create smaller texture atlases, not larger ones, which then defies the purpose of the texture atlas. #4 is not necessarily fps enhancing or generally applicable. -1 to the answer because the advice is about as helpful as "Don't do drugs" with the exception of #1.

Comment: you might want to consider using smaller textures on retina devices when it comes to performance vs look